# Detecting a Web Push notification in a Xamarin WebView

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-webview

I have a website that I am displaying in an app(Android and iOS) using Xamarin Webview. My site has web push notifications. I would like to detected those push notifications and create a local push notification natively. How can I find an entry point for when the Web push notification happens?

I tried looking at the webview docs and found nothing.

Edit:

Passing the device token using the invoke, and triggering a remote notification was the solution I ended up with.

Comment: The webview doesn't has a such api can do this. You can add js function to invoke native code to send a local notification when your website receives a web notification.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Thanks for the info. I will use JSInvoke.